# How to check in JS that PHP removed data from DB?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I need to know either my PHP script could delete some data from data base, or couldn't. 
For example I have JS function `public void removeNumber();` How i can to know that data was removed correctly? May be i must to return from server some String  that indicates success or failure attempting to remove data from db?  `public String removeNumber();` What is best practices? I know that better to throw exception, but in this case client and server both must know about Exception class (class mapping). 
P.S. 
I use ajax.

Comment: you should use ajax to make async calls from js frontend to php bakend  where you can perform db queries and echo some results

Comment: Those look more like Java functions than Javascript. Especially with the accessor and return type properties. And especially with the Exception class, since Javascript has neither an object by that name nor classes.

Comment: Why don't you show a sample of your existing JavaScript ajax and PHP code so that you can get some more specific advice? (And I second what Havvy said: the functions you quote are definitely not JavaScript functions.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ajax would be an easier & better solution. And using jquery ajax would be easier, like.

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: "your_php_page_url",
 data: {}, //pass parameter as you need
 success: function(response) {
   //its the response from php page indicating db deletion was successful or not
   // like "deleted" or "failed"
 } 
});

//and in php you could do
if($yourDbRowDeleted)  {
  echo "deleted";
}
else {
  echo "failed";
}
exit;
```

Hope it helps